# Detect small object in big grayscale image with Yolo v4 algorithm

Tags: image, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolo

I want to train a model to detect manhole covers from ortho photo.

[image: example of manhole cover located on the middle left]
[image: example of ortho photo]

I know how to do with images like the one offered in [open image dataset](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/index.html)

But here I have two difficulties:

1. The objects to be detected are small (about 30 * 30) compared to the size of the image (2500*2500)
2. And my images are in black and white.

I think we need to modify the conf file (.cfg). but I don't know how... Do you have any idea ?

[Link if you would like to test yolo algorithm on codelab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_GdoqCJWXsChrOiY8sZMr_zbr_fH-0Fg)

Comment: Did you find an answer yet? I wanted exactly the same thing. Train yolov4 for Grayscale images.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the width= and height = field in yolo-obj.cfg file to high resolution values.